# Convert image to Visio diagram?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, diagrams, microsoft-visio-2010

I'm trying to convert a simple diagram (boxes and arrows) into a Visio chart. There are lots of these boxes and arrows, however, so this will be a pain to do by hand.

Is there a way to convert an image to a Visio diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, there are a few tools available to convert an image to a Visio diagram. One of them is [Image Converter for Visio](https://web.archive.org/web/20130411104126/http://dmitryivanov.net/image-converter-for-visio/), which pretends to even be able to *"Add connection points to shapes"*.

While I haven't personally tested such tools, I would be highly surprised if they would work for something other than the most basic situations. Not because of [the reason mentioned by SecurityMatt](https://superuser.com/questions/398005/convert-image-to-visio-diagram#comment451907_398092)¹, but because image to vector conversions are known for not working very well. Even Live Trace feature in Adobe Illustrator is not working perfectly well, while Adobe invested a huge amount of effort in this feature.

Images are not rendered perfectly well. For example, if we were exporting the same diagram, the images would not be identical at pixel level, for example because I have slightly changed the Clear Type options for my LCD screen. This makes the OCR of a diagram not obvious, not counting the fact that Visio diagrams can be customized by changing color, size, weight and other visual aspects of elements.

Visio can also embed ordinary images, which makes things even more difficult, especially if those images are acting as shapes (imagine having a network map where network devices are replaced from the ugly default ones available in Visio by some more graphical ones).

Conclusion: feel free to try the tool I referenced or similar tools, but don't expect magic from them.

---

<sup>¹ It seems to me that the case illustrated by SecurityMatt would be extremely rare. If the arrow is joined up behind an element, there is something wrong with the diagram. Why would somebody do that? Isn't the point of a diagram to make it visually clear what is joined where?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

No. Visio stores objects like rectangles and arrows as separate objects so that when you reload it from a file you can move the rectangles and arrows separately.

An image doesn't store a picture of an arrow as "oh, there's an arrow going from here to there", it stores it as a white pixel followed by a black pixel followed by a white pixel and so on.

In short, information is destroyed when converting from Visio to an image - and that means there isn't enough information to convert it properly back again. The best you can do is import the image into visio, but sadly you won't be able to move the objects on the image independently of one-another.

More generally, attempting to glean information from a picture is an active research topic for artificial intelligence, but sadly there isn't a simple answer for taking a picture and breaking it down into its constituent parts.

Comment: There's plenty of information to get from a simple image to a simple Visio diagram. If OCR is possible, this functionality is certainly possible to. The question was just whether or not it had been implemented yet in Visio, which it sounds like it has not.

Comment: If a rectangle overlaps an arrow, it is not possible to work out whether the arrow is joined up underneath the rectangle - hence information is lost. OCR can make guesses as to the original, but OCR cannot recover the lost information, regardless of how smart it is.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your simple diagram is not in the format of Simple Vector Graphics (SVG). Therefore, this will likely not answer your question. But it is related, and this may resolve issues for some other people who may be directed to this page. If your diagram/image is in the format of SVG, or you're able to convert/export your image to SVG from your imaging program, then you can import the graphics in Visio (I'm using 2013) with some degree of success.